# What are bone matrices?

Tags: python, armature, bones

I tried looking everywhere but everything I've found so far seems to assume that I already know what it is.

Thanks!

Comment: I know how you feel, I'm not exactly the best person to explain them, but, in basic 3D game development, the matrix is pretty much the bone itself (typically known as a joint), they're basically used to  transform the vertices of a model through multiplication (dot), and hold all of the location, rotation, and scale transformations.